# How to "unwind" a core dump in gdb

Tags: c, gdb

I'm not sure if this is the correct wording of the issue, but let's take the following example where I have a program that will crash/abort:

```
#include <assert.h>

int main(void)
{
    int z=2;
    assert (z>5);
}
```

And if I compile it with debugging and then run it:

```
$ gcc -ggdb3 a.c -o a.o && ./a.o
a.o: a.c:8: main: Assertion `z>5' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Now I'll open it up in gdb to see if I can inspect the program:

```
$ gdb a.o core

Core was generated by `./a.o'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
51      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
```

If I now "run" the program with `r` I will get something like this (from gdb-dashboard viewer):

[image]

My question is the stack is now pretty deep into the C runtime / linux:

```
─── Stack ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
[0] from 0x00007ffff7a22f47 in __GI_raise+199 at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
[1] from 0x00007ffff7a248b1 in __GI_abort+321 at abort.c:79
[2] from 0x00007ffff7a1442a in __assert_fail_base+330 at assert.c:92
[3] from 0x00007ffff7a144a2 in __GI___assert_fail+66 at assert.c:101
[4] from 0x00005555555546ce in main+52 at a.c:8
```

Is it possible that I can unwind the stack to where the error was triggered:

```
[4] from 0x00005555555546ce in main+52 at a.c:8
```

So that I can see what the registers, variables, etc. were at that point? Another way to phrase the question is "How do I ignore things outside my code when inspecting a core dump / gdb" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a stab at this:

1. To travel up or down the callstack, use [`up|down`](http://kirste.userpage.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gdb/gdb_7.html). In this case we do `up 4` to get back to `main`:

   ```
   >>> up 4
   #4  0x000055555555467e in main () at a.c:7
   7           assert (z>5);
   ```
2. `info frame` and `info locals` can tell us high-level information about the function:

   ```
   >>> info locals
   z = 2
   __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ = "main"

   >>> info frame
   Stack level 4, frame at 0x7fffffffe0e0:
    rip = 0x55555555467e in main (a.c:7); saved rip = 0x7ffff7a05b97
    caller of frame at 0x7fffffffe0c0
    source language c.
    Arglist at 0x7fffffffe0d0, args:
    Locals at 0x7fffffffe0d0, Previous frame's sp is 0x7fffffffe0e0
    Saved registers:
     rbp at 0x7fffffffe0d0, rip at 0x7fffffffe0d8
   ```
3. For example, given the above, we can make a guess that the un-optimized assembly would put `z` into `%rbp-4` and we can examine its value there:

   ```
   >>> x/d $rbp-4
   0x7fffffffe0cc: 2

   # or, in long-form to ensure our rbp address above from `info` is the same:
   >>> x/d 0x7fffffffe0d0-4
   0x7fffffffe0cc: 2
   ```